# Ws2812B strip required AWG

Tags: power-supply, led-strip, awg, ws2812b

I’m looking to setup 6 runs of WS2812B strips at 10 meters length each (2 rolls of 30/m each).

I selected a 5v 100 amp psu and plan to power each strip by supplying power at one end and in the middle.

I think standard 22awg will be adaqute for running the data lines back to the controller. However I’m not sure about distributing the 5v. I’m thinking to run 2 larger wires from the psu and branching 6 wires of each of those. What wires sizes would be best to use, and distances could be achieved? Would there be a better setup?

Comment: based on cost and need, i would run 16awg trunks and 20awg branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have 30 LEDs/m and each LED consumes 50mA at full brightness. You get max 15A per 10m strip. Considering [this](https://xtronics.com/wiki/Wire-Gauge_Ampacity.html) table a AWG 18 wire could support this current. Depending on your specific application (ambient temperature, max supported temperature of cable isolation, single wire or bundle, etc.) you need to derate the maximum supported current and choose a bigger awg size. Also keep in mind the voltage drop caused by cable resistance and the stripe itself.

To achieve equal brightness of all leds of one strip connect +5V on one end and GND on the other end of each strip.

Comment: The WS2812b controls brightness by constant current and PWM. I think if the supply voltage isn't too low, it does not affect brightness.

Comment: good point. supply voltage still should not fall below 3.5V which is more likely to happen if supplied from one side only

Comment: Thank you for the info so far. The psu has 3 output terminals. Based on that table, I would do 3 14awg wires to 3 distribution blocks, and then from there branch out with 2 20 awg wires each strip. Wire lengths for each 10 meter strip will probably be 12 ft and 28 ft. 16 ft of the 28 ft would be a single wire in a 1/2 pvc plumbing pipe. The whole setup will be at room temperature and occasionally room temperature will be 85-90 f.

Comment: does the psu maybe has terminals for external voltage feedback? (to mask the voltage drop of the cable).

Comment: Here’s what I was planning to use. https://www.jameco.com/z/SE-600-5-MEAN-WELL-AC-to-DC-Power-Supply-Single-Output-5-Volt-100-Amp-500-Watt_374002.html

Comment: so it got a remote sensing Interface. you should use it. otherwise you most likely will get problems, at least at full brightness. You need to keep the cables of the individual strips short because you can only connect the remote sense inputs to your power distribution point.

Comment: Can’t I run a thin wire to the furthest connection point back to RS?

Comment: this would normally be the correct solution. But in this case it is unfortunately not possible because you are splitting the supply. Consider the following: you connect your sense wire directly to led strip #1; lets assume led strip #1 is at full brightness and therefore consumes max current resulting in max voltage drop on led strip #1 power cable; the supply will raise its voltage to compensate for mentioned voltage drop; any other led strip which is consuming less current than strip #1 will see a higher voltage than 5V, which may be to high (datasheet states 5.3V max supply)

Comment: Ah makes sense! Would it be best to then connect 3 sense wires to the distribution blocks and then connect all those back to the PSU's RS?

Answer (score 0):

The voltage drop in the strip itself will be too high for 10 meter strip.
Split the strip up in parts of 1 to 2 meters. Then you are only dealing with 2-3 Amps max per strip.

You can hook power up with 1mm<sup>2</sup>, or 0.5mm<sup>2</sup> on both sides of the strip. This allows you to use the same wire going up to the strip without much drop.

Since you're dealing with an 100A PSU, fuse each branch.